# Retrieve all accesses from a certain group/project in MicroStrategy

Tags: export-to-csv, audit, microstrategy

For audit purposes, I am in need of an export from MicrcoStrategy -that could retrieve to a .csv for example- all accesses from a certain group/project, so I can match´em with a report from Active Directory. Is there any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Command Manager has a way to do this.  Command Manager has a built-in list of command that you can run against your projects/I-server/etc. There should be something like `LIST ALL PRIVILEGES ...` or `LIST ALL PERMISSIONS ...` as a part of that.